# Custom iPhone storyboard segue doesn't work properly

Tags: iphone, controller, storyboard, segue

I want to load another view controller so the current slides up while the new one is coming from bottom, it works but I don't get the subviews (buttons disappear and I only get the blank view), how to fix it?

Current code is:

```
-(void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceVC = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationVC = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                     animations:^{ 
                         destinationVC.view.frame=CGRectMake(destinationVC.view.frame.origin.x, 480, destinationVC.view.frame.size.width, destinationVC.view.frame.size.height);
                         sourceVC.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -480);
                         destinationVC.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -480);

                     }];

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that VC already loaded inside animation? Why you use VC? U can animate separate views...

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 views for your viewController, and set second view origin.y = window.height
 Then animate like this -

```
CGRect outFrame = CGRectMake(0, 320, 320, 322);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f 
                      delay:delay
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                 animations:^{
                     fromView.frame = outFrame;
                     toView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 322);
                 } completion:nil];
```

something like this...

Comment: How can I add another view ti viewController in storyboard?
It doesn't allow me to add it...

Comment: mm... sorry, I forgot that you use storyboard